# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to an object

Tags: java, arraylist

I keep getting this error and I'm not sure how to resolve it, I have an `ArrayList` of object arrays, I can store the elements but I'm not sure how to get the elements back out, Is there anything here that's obviously wrong?

```
ArrayList<Object[]> pA = processArray(statii);
        for(Object pAs: pA){
            Toast.makeText(TweetstagramActivity.this, pAs[0], //error occurs here
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
for(Object pAs: pA) {
```

You want:

```
 for (Object[] pAs : pA) {
```

The first is *legal* because any `Object[]` reference is also a valid `Object` reference - but then you can't use `pAs[0]` as you're trying to in the loop.

(I'd also encourage you to use more descriptive variable names, btw.)

Comment: I believe this is exactly what was causing it, thanks for your help!